# Unity - ARCore Instant PreView Error while:Attempte debug HelloAR example app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm trying to dubug ARCore HelloAR sample app with Unity.
The ARCore instant preview app start on my phone and then crash.

I get this Error:

```
Attempted to enable 'Light Estimation' which is not yet supported by Instant Preview.
Please build and run on device to use this feature.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogErrorFormat(String, Object[])
GoogleARCoreInternal.InstantPreviewManager:LogLimitedSupportMessage(String, Boolean) (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/InstantPreview/Scripts/InstantPreviewManager.cs:177)
GoogleARCoreInternal.InstantPreviewManager:ValidateSessionConfig(ARCoreSessionConfig) (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/InstantPreview/Scripts/InstantPreviewManager.cs:123)
GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreAndroidLifecycleManager:_OnEarlyUpdate() (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Managers/ARCoreAndroidLifecycleManager.cs:295)
GoogleARCoreInternal.ARPrestoCallbackManager:_EarlyUpdateTrampoline() (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Managers/ARPrestoCallbackManager.cs:188)
GoogleARCoreInternal.NativeApi:Update()
GoogleARCoreInternal.<UpdateLoop>d__19:MoveNext() (at Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/InstantPreview/Scripts/InstantPreviewManager.cs:411)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

When I build and run the app on my phone it works fine.
I am using:

- Editor version 2019.4.3f1.
- AR Foundation 2.1.8.
- ARCore SDK for   Unity v1.18.0.
- XR Legacy Input Helpers 2.1.4
- multiplayer HLAPI 1.0.6
- My phone I'm debugging with is Samsung S9 - An ARCore supported device
- I  include Android Build Support during installation WITH Unity Hub

Please Help me I couldn't find any solution.

Gil.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I stumbled upon it because ARCore doesn't mention that Light Estimation is not supported at all while in Instant Preview in their documentation.

Comment: The problem was with my weak graphic card :(